# Excel: How to reorganize longitudinal data by merging cells based on year

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Now I have some longitudinal data in the following format:

| id | year_1b | year_2 | Variable_1b | Variable_2 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | 2018 | 2020 | 1.1 | 1.2 | ... |
| 10002 | 2018 | 2020 | 0.3 | 0.5 | ... |
| 10002 | 2018 | 2020 | 1.8 | 2.6 | ... |
| ⋮ | ⋮ | ⋮ | ⋮ | ⋮ | ⋱ |

In order to analyze data in STATA, I want to reorganize it into the following style:

| id | year | Variable | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | 2018 | 1.1 | ... |
| 10002 | 2018 | 0.3 | ... |
| 10002 | 2018 | 1.8 | ... |
| ⋮ | ⋮ | ⋮ | ⋮ |
| 10001 | 2020 | 1.2 | ... |
| 10002 | 2020 | 0.5 | ... |
| 10002 | 2020 | 2.6 | ... |

I'm using one variable in the example above. Excluding `year` and `id`, I have 1410 columns in this "_1b" and "_2" format, and I have 1000 rows. These are the 705 survey questions (705 * 2 = 1410) asked to 1000 respondents in year 2018 (variable name ending in _1b) and year 2020 (in _2).

Is there any point-and-click or VBA tricks I can do to reorganize the data quickly?

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You can use Power Query for this and I can help you with an answer, but the details will depend on the structure of the rest of the variables. Could you edit the question and include either the full list of variable names or a representative sample of the same?

Comment: If your excel is new enough you could use the `HSTACK` formula

Comment: @FlexYourData Thanks for the suggestion! The dataset is large. It has 1410 variables, in the following style: "agekdbrn_1b, agekdbrn_2, astrolgy_1b, astrolgy_2 ... workwhts_1b, workwhts_2" (these are questions answered by respondents in year 2018 and 2020). And it has 1000 respondents (each with an unique id).

Comment: @Greenhill OK no problem. I worked with survey data for over 15 years so I understand the struggle. Are you looking for your case-granularity to be respondentid/year? Or do you need further separation by topic/loop, etc?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in Power Query using
To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range` or `from within sheet`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

```
let

//Change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMjQwMDBU0lEyMjC0AFNGBkDKUM8QTBopxepA1BhhqDHQMwaTpnjUGOqBOXpmSrGxAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [id = _t, year_1b = _t, year_2 = _t, Variable_1b = _t, Variable_2 = _t]),
    
//You can let PQ detect the types automatically
//Select all the columns, then Transform=>Detect Data Types
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"id", Int64.Type}, {"year_1b", Int64.Type}, {"year_2", Int64.Type}, {"Variable_1b", type number}, {"Variable_2", type number}}),

//Select the "id" column and unpivot the rest
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"id"}, "Attribute", "Value"),

//Since Variable and Year have matching suffixes, we can split on the underscore
//  and then Group by the portion after the underscore
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Attribute", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("_", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Attribute.1", "Attribute.2"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Attribute.1", type text}, {"Attribute.2", type text}}),

//Pivot each subtable
//FillDown the "year" column and delete the rows with null in the Variable column
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type1", {"Attribute.2"}, {
        {"Pivot", (t)=>
            Table.SelectRows(
                Table.FillDown(
                    Table.RemoveColumns(
                        Table.Pivot(
                            Table.AddIndexColumn(t,"Index"),
                                List.Distinct(t[Attribute.1],Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase),"Attribute.1","Value"),
                        {"Attribute.2","Index"}),
                    {"year"}),
                each [Variable] <> null), type table[id=Int64.Type, year=Int64.Type, Variable=number]
        }}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Attribute.2"}),
    #"Expanded Pivot" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Pivot", {"id", "year", "Variable"})
in
    #"Expanded Pivot"
```

***Source***
[image]

***Results***
[image]